# Convert FCM token into a representation that works as document id in Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to store relations between FCM tokens and registered users in a Firestore collection. To make it easy to delete invalid entries (e.g. if a different user logs in on the same client), I want to give them document ids that are derived from the two relevant values: the `uid` of the current user and the fcm token in the follwing manner:

```
<fcm-token>_<uid>
```

Unfortunately the FCM token contains characters that are not allowed in an document id. So I thought about hashing the FCM token and found md5 and sha256 as possible options, but both have different issues:

- sha256 as base64 string works as expected but in some cases the result contains a `/` which breaks the document references --> can't use reliably
- md5 as base64 works as well and although I didn't find a `/` in my test data yet, I assume that it can happen as well (the base64 spec allows `/`, so I have to expect it) --> can't use reliably
- converting any of those to hex instead of base64 doesn't seem to work: I'm getting `PERMISSION_DENIED: evaluation error`. Unfortunately I don't know how to debug the output of the hashing function in the rules file..

I'm testing this with the Firestore emulator and `@firebase/rules-unit-testing`.

This is the code, you can replace the respective lines to try the different combinations:

The test:

```js
import {
  initializeTestEnvironment,
  assertSucceeds
} from '@firebase/rules-unit-testing'

import crypto from 'crypto'

let testEnv

before(async () => {
  await initializeTestEnvironment({ /* init stuff that works fine in all other cases */})
})

after(async () => {
  await testEnv.cleanup()
})

function hash(text) {
  return crypto.createHash('sha256').update(text).digest('base64')
  // return crypto.createHash('md5').update(text).digest('base64')
  // return crypto.createHash('sha256').update(text).digest('hex')
  // return crypto.createHash('md5').update(text).digest('hex')
}

describe('Store FCM token' () => {
  it('should follow the expected pattern', () => {
    const dbAlice = testEnv.authenticatedContext('alice').firestore()

    await assertSucceeds(
      setDoc(doc(dbAlice, 'tokens', hash('abc123') + '_alice'), {
        uid: 'alice',
        fcmToken: 'abc123'
      })
    )
  })
})
```

`firestore.rules`:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{databaseId}/documents {
    match /{documentId=**} {
        allow read, write: if false;
    }

    match /tokens/{docId} {
      function docIdFollowsNamingPattern() {
        return docId == hashing.sha256(request.resource.data.fcmToken).toBase64() + '_' + request.resource.data.uid
        // return docId == hashing.md5(request.resource.data.fcmToken).toBase64() + '_' + request.resource.data.uid
        // return docId == hashing.sha256(request.resource.data.fcmToken).toHexString() + '_' + request.resource.data.uid
        // return docId == hashing.md5(request.resource.data.fcmToken).toHexString() + '_' + request.resource.data.uid
      }

      allow create: if
        docIdFollowsNamingPattern();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Questions:

- is the general approach worth to follow. If not: what would you recommend?
- how can I fix hashing to get a result that is the same in the rules and in NodeJS and also works as a document id?

Comment: I found the issue and fixed it (see answer below). I would still be interested to understand if this apprach is worth to follow in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I got it. After finding out about [`debug()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.debug) for Firestore rules, I learned that the local function outputs the hash in lower case while the function in the rules outputs it in upper case.

Adding `.toUpperCase()` to the local hash function solved it:

```js
function hash(text) {
  return crypto.createHash('sha256').update(text).digest('hex').toUpperCase()
  // return crypto.createHash('md5').update(text).digest('hex').toUpperCase()
}
```

It works for both, md5 as well as sha256.